# How to get the max two values from each row and concatenate them in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created Table 1 for vehicles, and it has color values (`Red`, `Blue`, `Yellow`). I have to update Table 2's `Colors` field by getting each row's max two values field names of Table 1 and concatenate them.

By using a nested if-else, I could get the first max value, but could not get the second max values of each row.

Table 2 field `Color` has the expected update result:

[image]

**TABLE 1**

```
Vehicle  Red   Blue  Yellow
Honda    10     20    25
Yamaha   12     10    22
Suzuki   25     30    40
```

**TABLE 2**

```
Vehicle   Color
Honda     Blue/Yellow
Yamaha    Red/Yellow 
Suzuki    Blue/Yellow
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQL server     ---------- version details    Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
 Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: This may help with some guidance - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71045/1313067 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just three colors -- assuming all values are unique -- you can get by with `case` expressions:

```
select ((case when red > blue and red > yellow then 'red'
              when blue > yellow then 'blue'
              else 'yellow'
          end) + '/' +
         (case when red > blue and red < yellow or red < blue and red > yellow then 'red'
               when blue > red and blue < yellow or blue < red and blue < yellow then 'blue'
               else 'yellow'
          end)
        )
```

The results are slightly different from your stated results.  The dominant color is first -- but that seems like a benefit.

If you want to use `cross apply`, then one (relatively) simple method is:

```
select max(c.color) + '/' + min(c.color)
from t cross apply
     (select top (2) v.*
      from (values ('red', red), ('blue', blue), ('yellow', yellow)) v(color, val)
      order by val desc
     ) c;
```

The colors are not ordered by their value.  You can easily arrange that:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then c.color en) + '/' + max(case when seqnum = 1 then c.color end)
from t cross apply
     (select v.*, row_number() over (order by v.val desc) as seqnum
      from (values ('red', red), ('blue', blue), ('yellow', yellow)) v(color, val)
     ) c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cte`  :

```
with t as (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by Vehicle order by ColrVal) Seq
        from table1 t1 cross apply (
              values ('Red', Red), ('Bule', Blue), ('Yellow', Yellow) 
             ) t2 (Colr, ColrVal)
)

select Vehicle,
       stuff ( (select '/'+Colr 
                from t t2
                where t2.Vehicle = t1.Vehicle and t2.Seq > 1
                for xml path('')
                ), 1, 1, ''
             ) as Color
from t t1
group by Vehicle;
```

However, this uses the `row_number()` function to get the top most colors and doing the group_concat using *xml* method with `stuff()` function.