# How to retrieve the column name which has maximum value by comparing the values from multiple columns using 'Case' statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

How to retrieve the column name which has maximum value by comparing the values from multiple columns using 'Case' statements

For eg : there are more than 10 columns .

```
  A B C D E       Result  
  1 2 3 1 5        E
```

column E has the highest no and in the result column i should get 'E' as the answer.

Here A B C D E Result are columns .. By comparing the values from A,B,C,D,E i should get the column name which has maximum no in the result column using Case expression.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Here are several solutions depending on your database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns

Comment: Is there some reason you specifically want to use CASE, or are you really asking for any method to get the largest value?

Comment: No specifically i want to try using  'Case'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CASE? Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test (a, b, c, d) as
  2    (select 1, 2, 3, 1 from dual)
  3  select
  4    case when a >= b and a >= c and a >= d then a
  5         when b >= a and b >= c and b >= d then b
  6         when c >= a and c >= b and c >= d then c
  7         when d >= a and d >= b and d >= c then d
  8    end result
  9  from test;

    RESULT
----------
         3

SQL>
```

Comment: It is right and simple when we have only fewer columns .But there are totally 15 columns . So I need simplest way to get the same result.

Comment: Well, the simplest way would be one of those provided by Gordon. However, you said that it *must* be CASE, so - that's how it looks like. You'll have to do a lot of typing and do it carefully, otherwise you'll get the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

Most dialects of SQL support `greatest()` and `least()`:

```
select greatest(a, b, c, d, e) as greatest,
       least(a, b, c, d, e) as least
```

Those that don't typically have some other mechanism.  For instance, SQLite overloads `min()` and `max()`:

```
select min(a, b, c, d, e) as greatest,
       max(a, b, c, d, e) as least
```

Or, in SQL Server, I would use `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(val) as greatest, min(val) as least
      from (values (a), (b), (c), (d), (e)) v(val)
     ) v;
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't believe that... Typical design issue. A lot of headaches come from the fact that database designers who are not supposed to touch a database at all.

You want get the max value from different column : meaning that the data inside those columns have the same context. We are here comparing apple, orange, peach and bananas !

Since you are comparing data which have the same context, they should all have been in the same column. Enabling people trying to help you avoiding to scratch their brain. pfff...

My solution is kinda barbaric...

```
create table jeez(
  jeez_id serial primary key,
  row_id integer,
  row_value integer)


insert into jeez (row_id, row_value)
select TheTableWithNoName_id, column_a from TheTableWithNoName
union
select TheTableWithNoName_id, column_b from TheTableWithNoName
union
select TheTableWithNoName_id, column_c from TheTableWithNoName
union
select TheTableWithNoName_id, column_d from TheTableWithNoName
```

So now you can do :

```
select row_id, max(row_value)
from jeez
group by 1
order by 1
```

Unbelievable.