# How to get max value of column values in a record ? (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I wanna get max value of each rows, not max value of a field.
For example, when I have a sample_table like this:

**sample_table**

```
|col1|col2|col3|
|--------------|
| 1  | 0  | 0  |
| 0  | 2  | 0  |
| 2  | 0  | 0  |
| 0  | 0  | 3  |
```

And the query and result I want is something like this:

**query**

```
SELECT SOME_GET_MAX_VAL_FUNC(col1, col2, col3) AS max_val FROM sample_table;
```

**result**

```
|max_val|
|-------|
|   1   |
|   2   |
|   2   |
|   3   |
```

I want some solution to replace `SOME_GET_MAX_VAL_FUNC` .
If it is nearly impossible in SQL, why is it? (I'm new to SQL and BigQuery)

**note**

- The number of `col`s maybe very big, like `col1, col2, ... col200` .
  So the solution of using `CASE` would be hard to me. [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)
- Particularly, the rest columns other than the max value are equal to `0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want `GREATEST` :

```
SELECT GREATEST(col1, col2, col3) 
FROM table t;
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

> The number of cols maybe very big, like col1, col2, ... col200

having above in mind - below is optimal solution (BigQuery Standard SQL) which does not require explicit typing of all columns names like in `GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, ..., col200)`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  (SELECT MAX(value) FROM 
    UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r':([^,}]+)')) value
  ) max_val
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

If to apply to smple_table in your question result will be

```
Row     col1    col2    col3    max_val  
1       1       0       0       1    
2       0       2       0       2    
3       2       0       0       2    
4       0       0       3       3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great too! Typing columns does not matter cuz I generate SQL by Python though