# How to get top 3 columns and their values across multiple columns (dynamically) in BigQuery

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a table that looks like this

```
select 'Alice' AS ID, 1 as col1, 3 as col2, -2 as col3, 9 as col4
union all
select 'Bob' AS ID, -9 as col1, 2 as col2, 5 as col3, -6 as col4
```

I would like to get the top 3 absolute values for each record across the four columns and then format the output as a dictionary or STRUCT like below

```
select 
'Alice' AS ID, [STRUCT('col4' AS column, 9 AS value), STRUCT('col2',3), STRUCT('col3',-2)] output
union all
select
'Bob' AS ID, [STRUCT('col1' AS column, -9 AS value), STRUCT('col4',-6), STRUCT('col3',5)]
 output
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjM7L.png)

I would like it to be dynamic, so avoid writing out columns individually. It could go up to 100 columns that change

For more context, I am trying to get the top three features from the batch local explanations output in Vertex AI
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/classification-regression/get-batch-predictions

I have looked up some examples, would like something similar to the second answer here [How to get max value of column values in a record ? (BigQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758357/how-to-get-max-value-of-column-values-in-a-record-bigquery)

EDIT: the data is actually structured like this. If this can be worked with more easily, this would be a better option to work from

```
select 'Alice' AS ID,  STRUCT(1 as col1, 3 as col2, -2 as col3, 9 as col4) AS featureAttributions
union all
SELECT  'Bob' AS ID, STRUCT(-9 as col1, 2 as col2, 5 as col3, -6 as col4) AS featureAttributions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query.

```sql
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column, value) ORDER BY ABS(value) DESC LIMIT 3) output
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM sample_table UNPIVOT (value FOR column IN (col1, col2, col3, col4))
  ) 
 GROUP BY ID;
```

**Query results**

[image]

##### Dynamic Query

> *I would like it to be dynamic, so avoid writing out columns individually*

You need to consider a dynamic SQL for this. By refering to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758357/how-to-get-max-value-of-column-values-in-a-record-bigquery) from @Mikhail you linked in the post, you can write a dynamic query like below.

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column, value) ORDER BY ABS(value) DESC LIMIT 3) output
    FROM (
      SELECT * FROM sample_table UNPIVOT (value FOR column IN (%s))
    ) 
   GROUP BY ID
""", ARRAY_TO_STRING(
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (ID) FROM sample_table LIMIT 1)), r'"([^,{]+)":'), ',')
);
```

**For updated sample table**

```sql
SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column, value) ORDER BY ABS(value) DESC LIMIT 3) output
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, featureAttributions.* FROM sample_table) 
   UNPIVOT (value FOR column IN (col1, col2, col3, col4))
  ) 
 GROUP BY ID;
```

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(column, value) ORDER BY ABS(value) DESC LIMIT 3) output
    FROM (
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, featureAttributions.* FROM sample_table)
     UNPIVOT (value FOR column IN (%s))
    ) 
   GROUP BY ID
""", ARRAY_TO_STRING(
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT featureAttributions FROM sample_table LIMIT 1)), r'"([^,{]+)":'), ',')
);
```