# SQL get all columns from max aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table like This:

| ID (Not PK) | time_to_prioritize | extra_info_1 | extra_info_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | info_1 | info_1 |
| 001 | 1 | info_1 | info_1 |
| 001 | 2 | info_1_last | info_1_last |
| 002 | 1 | info_2 | info_2 |
| 002 | 2 | info_2_last | info_2_last |
| 003 | 0 | info_3_last | info_3_last |

My objective is to get the *max(time_to_prioritize)* of all distinct ID's along with the extra columns, like this:

| ID (Not PK) | time_to_prioritize | extra_info_1 | extra_info_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2 | info_1_last | info_1_last |
| 002 | 2 | info_2_last | info_2_last |
| 003 | 0 | info_3_last | info_3_last |

I got stuck at

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM my_table
ORDER BY time_to_prioritize DESC
```

I am trying to join it with itself, but with no results.
What is the next step to achieve the result ?
thanks.

P.S. the result on [SQL MAX of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns)
does not help me, bc that link is the max of every column, I need the max of only 1 column, along with the rest of the data

Comment: something like  '''Select Max (time) from my_table Groupby(ID) ''' ?
My issue with this approach is that I cannot get the rest of the columns

Answer (score 5):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` function as the following:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.time_to_prioritize, T.extra_info_1, T.extra_info_2
FROM
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_to_prioritize DESC) rn
  FROM my_table
) T
WHERE T.rn=1
ORDER BY T.ID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wKv9vC8h).

Comment: I ended up using this solution.
it feels more readable to me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach with `TOP 1` can be employed, though it requires some fixes.

If you want to get the first row with respect the ordering, you use `TOP 1`, though if you want to get the first row *for each ID*, then you require the clause `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, where the tie should happen to the ordering value. If you want to make your three "interesting rows" to be tied in the ordering, you should use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function inside the `ORDER BY` clause as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
FROM my_table
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY time_to_prioritize DESC)
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EV-8Bn2H).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(time_to_prioritize) AS MAXtime_to_prioritize ,* FROM my_table
GROUP BY time_to_prioritize ,extra_info_1,  extra_info_2
ORDER BY time_to_prioritize DESC
```

Comment: This only works on MySQL with `only_full_group_by` set to off