# Effectively mimic T-SQL LEAST in earlier version (2017)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, min

So, I got myself in a situation where I have 36 columns and need to essentially do a "MIN" on ALL those columns.  Not a MIN by grouping, rather, what I need is what the 2022-and-after LEAST function does.

Does anyone have any suggestion of how I could accomplish this?  I did some research and reading, but didn't find anything that wasn't IIF, which, with 36 columns, well, it seems a bit uglier-than-ugly.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Please provide sample data and desired results (even if less columns) to illustrate.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4067/find-max-value-from-multiple-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022/sql-max-of-multiple-columns

Comment: @rhythmWasaLurker Thank you, that link was spot on.  I used option 1 on https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4067/find-max-value-from-multiple-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/  and it worked just like LEAST which is precisely what I needed.
Thanks, you should put that as an answer maybe?  Everyone please don't crucify me if that's wrong, I'm new-ish to stack overflow, thanks again.